# Why does it matter at what point I replace?

Tags: numerics, replacement, machine-precision, mathematical-optimization

I need to find four orthogonal linear combinations of complicated functions, that vanish at four different points.

I use (LK4 is defined below, but its shape should have nothing to do with my problem)

`NMinimize[LK4[{a, b, c, d}, I, 0, 0, 0, 0], {a, b, c, d}]`

and get a result, as replacement rule (using MachinePrecision)

`{3.3493*10^-17, {a -> 2.34594, b -> -1.80385, c -> 2.51873, 
  d -> 0.2406}}`

Now if I create a vector for these coefficients

`P1 = {a, b, c, d}/.%[[2]]`

and call the function with this vector I get a different result than by replacing directly in the function call:

`LK4[{a, b, c, d}, I, 0, 0, 0, 0]/.%%[[2]]` returns `3.3493*10^-17`, while `LK4[P1, I, 0, 0, 0, 0]` returns `0.373542`.

What's worse is that `LK4[({a, b, c, d}/.%%%%[[2]]), 0, 0, 0, 0]` also returns the inaccurate result `0.373542`.

What I wanted to do is find a linear combination that minimizes at the first spot, then define a coefficient vector from that and minimize at the second spot with the constraint that the coefficient vector has to be orthogonal to the first. `LK4[{a, b, c, d}, tau, xi1, xi2, x, y]` normalizes the coefficient vector btw.

How can I get Mathematica to assign appropriately precise values upon using the replacement rule?

I tried setting the precision to 100 instead of MachinePrecision, but with the very same results.

Definition of LK4:

```
    Phi[j_, qM_, x_, y_, tau_, xi1_, xi2_] := 
  Surd[2 qM Im[tau]/Abs[tau]^2, 4] Exp[
    I 2 Pi (xi1 x + xi2 y)]  Exp[- Pi I Conjugate[tau]/Abs[tau]^2 ( 
       j^2/qM + qM x^2) + 
     2 Pi I j Conjugate[tau]/Abs[tau]^2 (x + tau y)] * 
   N[EllipticTheta[3, 
     Pi Conjugate[tau]/Abs[tau]^2 (qM (x + tau y) - j), 
     Exp[ -Pi I Conjugate[tau]/Abs[tau]^2 qM]], 20];
PhiEven[j_, qM_, x_, y_, tau_, xi1_, xi2_] := 
  Phi[j, qM, x, y, tau, xi1, xi2] /; j == 0;
PhiEven[j_, qM_, x_, y_, tau_, xi1_, xi2_] := 
  Phi[j, qM, x, y, tau, xi1, xi2] /;  
   qM/2 \[Element] Integers && j == qM/2;
PhiEven[j_, qM_, x_, y_, tau_, xi1_, xi2_] := 
  1/Sqrt[2] (Phi[j, qM, x, y, tau, xi1, xi2] + 
     Phi[qM - j, qM, x, y, tau, xi1, xi2]);
PhiOdd[j_, qM_, x_, y_, tau_, xi1_, xi2_] := 
  1/Sqrt[2] (Phi[j, qM, x, y, tau, xi1, xi2] - 
      Phi[qM - j, qM, x, y, tau, xi1, xi2]) /; j != 0 && j != qM/2;
LK4[coeff_, tau_, xi1_, xi2_, x_, y_] := 
  Sum[coeff[[a]]/(Sqrt@Total[coeff^2]) PhiEven[a - 1, 6, x, y, tau, 
     xi1, xi2], {a, 1, 4}];
```

Comment: What is the definition of `f`?

Comment: updated the post with the lengthy definition

Comment: Your `LK4` function takes 6 arguments, whereas the `f` function in your example only takes three, a vector and two numbers. Those don't seem consistent. Can you explain further?

Comment: As I tried to explain abobe the last block of code, f is LK4 with tau = i and xi1 = xi2 = 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at

```
LK4[{a, b, c, d}, I, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What has happened is that the `a` in the argument `{a, b, c, d}` has been replaced by `{1, 2, 3, 4}` in the `Sum[..., {a, 1, 4}]` code in the definition of `LK4`.

If you change the definition of `LK4` to use a different iterator, you get consistent results:

```
LK4[coeff_, tau_, xi1_, xi2_, x_, y_] := 
 Sum[coeff[[a1]]/(Sqrt@Total[coeff^2]) PhiEven[a1 - 1, 6, x, y, tau, xi1, xi2],
 {a1, 1, 4}]
```

This happens because, according to the docs, `Sum` effectively uses [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) to "localize" the iterator variable `a`.  This means that any instances of `a` in the expression of the (evaluated) summand, such as an `a` in `coeff` argument `{a, b, c, d}`, will be replaced by `1`, `2`, etc.

Comment: Geez, this is embarrasing... Thank you!

Comment: @Neuneck You're welcome. It can be a convenient side-effect of `Sum`, `Table`, etc., but easy to overlook since it is hidden from view. If (1) the vector `coeff` is always real and (2) you make `PhiEven` have the `Attribute` [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html), then you can define `LK4` by `Normalize[coeff] . PhiEven[Range[0, 3], 6, x, y, tau, xi1, xi2]` without introducing a iterator to trap you. Alternatively, you could use `Total` and `Map`: `Total[coeff[[#]]/(Sqrt@Total[coeff^2]) PhiEven[# - 1, 6, x, y, tau, xi1, xi2] & /@ Range[4]]`.

Comment: That idea with Total works amazingly well! I generalized the definitions even and everything works as intended. +100 :P

Comment: @Neuneck, Thank you for the bonus.  Best