# How can I run a summation numerous times?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have been working on code for finding the Allan plot of generated white noise, however, I cannot figure out a way to automate it for a different range of numbers. My code is as follows:

```
WN = WhiteNoiseProcess[NormalDistribution[0, 10]];
data = RandomFunction[WN, {1, 10000}];
m = 50;
points = data["Values"];
yBinLst = Partition[points, m];
meanLst = Mean /@ yBinLst;

allanVar = 
    Sum[(meanLst[[i + 1]] - meanLst[[i]])^2, 
    {i, 1, (Length[meanLst] - 1)}]/(2 (Length[yBinLst] - 1))
```

I want to be able to run this numerous times for different values of m and create a list of each `m` value with the the respective `allanVar` output. I read about Module and Tables, but everything I try gives me errors. As the code is right now, I can manually change the value of `m` and get different values, however, it is not very efficient.

Comment: You could try and turn your allanVar into a function of m: allanVar[m_]:=...

Comment: Well, in the time it took me to write that comment and start messing with the code, @MichaelE2 had already written and posted a full answer so I'll refer you to that for what I meant  :-)

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you as well. I didn't expect such a complete answer so quickly. I posted this question and drove home, by the time I arrived, it had been answered. :O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to define a function that does your computation:

```
With[{WN = WhiteNoiseProcess[NormalDistribution[0, 10]]},
 aV[m_] := Module[{data, points, yBinLst, meanLst},
   data = RandomFunction[WN, {1, 10000}];
   points = data["Values"];
   yBinLst = Partition[points, m];
   meanLst = Mean /@ yBinLst;;

   Total[Differences[meanLst]^2]/(2 (Length[yBinLst] - 1))
   ]
 ]
```

Test:

```
SeedRandom[0];
aV[50]
(*  1.80707  *)
```

Iterating over values of `m` with [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)

```
SeedRandom[0];
Table[aV[m], {m, 10, 50, 10}]
(*  {9.153, 4.66112, 3.45167, 2.80704, 1.87839}  *)
```

Iterating over values of `m` with [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)

```
SeedRandom[0];
myValuesForM = {12, 33, 37, 50};
aV /@ myValuesForM
(*  {8.58519, 2.76198, 2.63612, 1.91234}  *)
```

Notes: The `Sum` is more efficiently computed with the built-in `Differences` and `Total`. Also `Power` (squaring) is vectorized so that squaring the whole list of differences is much more efficient on large amounts of data than squaring each difference separately.

---

*Random obfuscations*

```
Array[aV, 5, {10, 50}] (* where did they come up with this form for the iterator??? *)

myValuesForM /. m_Integer :> aV[m]

ClearAll[aV];
SetAttributes[aV, Listable]; (* makes aV[{a, b,...}] turn into {aV[a], aV[b],...} *)
(* def. above goes here *)
aV[myValuesForM]
```

...and finally, for those whose think hierarchical grouping is politically incorrect,

```
myValuesForM ~Part~ # & /* aV ~Array~ Length @ myValuesForM
```

More substitutes for the OP's `Sum[(meanLst[[i + 1]] - meanLst[[i]])^2, {i, 1, (Length[meanLst] - 1)}]/(2 (Length[yBinLst] - 1))`:

```
Norm[Differences[meanLst]]^2 (* from @Guess who it is. *)
#.# &@Differences[meanLst]   (* slightly faster *)
```

Comment: `Norm[Differences[meanLst]]^2` can also be used in place of `Total[Differences[meanLst]^2]`.

Comment: @Michael E2 I am curious, which is the better option, Map or Table? I have only been working with Mathematica for roughly 2 weeks intensively (which is to say, each step which stumps me, leads me into researching the best method, so intensity is subjective).

Comment: Actually, after some more musing, why not give `aV` the `Listable` attribute? @Sean, `Table[]` also happens to be usable for the `Map[]` example: `Table[aV[m], {m, myValuesForM}]`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. `#.# &@Differences[meanLst]` is a little faster than both.  Sure, why not `Listable`?

Comment: @SeanAlto For this application and as a new user, the differences are minor as both are comparably efficient. The most significant difference is the introduction of the dummy variable `m` in `Table` ([which can have side-effects](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83136)).  Getting familiar with `Map` (conceptually) gives one a good tool for thinking through problems involving arrays of things.  Other differences between `Map` and `Table` may be significant in different settings.  Try to do this with `Table`: `Map[f, {1, {2}, {{3}, 4}}, {-1}]`.